# Delphi getting TTask.IFuture without blocking main thread?

Tags: delphi, task, future

In the example below (from Embarcadero's manual), the MyValue will be retrieved after 3 seconds about. But, the main gui thread would be blocked by the MyValue := FutureObject.Value; call which will wait for the result.
If the Future code will take long, lets say 30 seconds, Windows will show a "... not responding" in the programs caption I guess.
So whats the purpose of this when it will block the main gui thread?
Is there any other way to get the result without blocking the main gui thread?

```
FutureObject := TTask.Future<Integer>(function: Integer
    begin
        Sleep(3000);
        Result := 16;
    end);
// …
MyValue := FutureObject.Value;
```

Comment: If you need to know, then you need to wait. Perhaps you are looking for an event driven approach. Some context would help. I suggest you buy a book on parallel processing and learn the concepts. Doesn't need to be delphi based, the concepts are the same for other oop languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, the [`IFuture.Value`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.IFuture.Value) property blocks the calling thread until another thread assigns a value.  So, if you read `Value` in the main thread, it is going to block the main thread until a value is ready.

If you must read `Value` in the main thread without blocking, you can either:

- use a timer or other asynchronous mechanism to periodically query the [`IFuture.Status`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.ITask.Status) property to check when the `IFuture` is ready to provide a value before actually reading it.
- have the parallel task signal the main thread when it is ready, and then the main thread can read the `Value` in its signal handler.

Comment: Thank you, answer accepted because it explains it very well for me.

Comment: Once you start signaling the main thread when you are ready, there's no longer any point in using a future.

Answer (score 2):

I know it might be a bit late but i solved it by creating a TTask that did the 
MyValue := FutureObject.Value

```
FutureObject := TTask.Future<Integer>(function: Integer
begin
    Sleep(3000);
    Result := 16;
end);
// …
TTask.Run(Procedure begin
MyValue := FutureObject.Value;
end);
```